# How to model hard surface sword

Tags: modeling

I want model a sword like in the image below, please give me some hints about how to model it:
I want any complete tutorial  I tried this model but I really don't know to use polygonal modeling or curve?
I am sorry for this.
Only one or tow tips I want man!

[image]

finally I did it:
[image]

Comment: Have have you tried so far? Where in the workflow are you stuck? What difficulties are you having? This is not the right place for tutorial requests.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for [BlendSwap](http://www.blendswap.com/requests) than BSE; you haven't even started modeling yet. This is more of a "can someone make me this model?".

Comment: It all depends on how you want to model it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first start by drawing or getting a top down view of the sword and starting there. It is a great way to understand the shape of the object you want to make.

From there, just stretch out a plane using extrude <kbd>E</kbd> and adding loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in edit mode) to add cuts where necessary.

I would suggest looking at some basic modelling tutorials if that doesn't make sense or doesn't help.